# Moving YTD MAX by group in Visual expression builder (data flow in ADF)

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory

I am new to visual expression builder language in ADF. I am not sure if I can calculate the moving YTD MAX (or average) by group for the following case in expression language:

I have sales data for different products in different periods, and I want to know the moving YTD (year to date) max sales amount by product.

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-window) in Data Flow.

My test:

1. Data of my source
   [image]

2.Setting of Window transformation
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Data preview of Window transformation
[image]